# How CDN operator will decide content fo me if i am using google public DNS

Tags: network, dns, google, geolocation

As i saw most of the internet is being load balanced even at DNS . And DNS load balancers takes decision on behalf of client's DNS . So I Am just curious to know if i will use 8.8.8.8 as nameserver in my ubuntu 12.04 box then what will be my location for the internet. Will my ISP's provided dns not be of any use. And Most importatntly is there be problem with CDN to know my location As my DNS will be geographicaly in somewhere in US always.

Comment: At least akamai will send you to (resolve the dns entries pointing to) the US datacenters. I don't think you would notice the slightly higher delay. The CDN might be using anycast addressing (I don't know if any of them do), so you might be even getting the "right" datacenter although the dns couldn't determine it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is not exactly very clear so I'll take a stab in the dark and try to interpret your question.

What DNS server you use has no bearing on your "location". That is entirely dependent on your public IP address. If you are using a home broadband, it is very likely that you will be using a public IP address shared with many other people through NAT.

Comment: sorry about that and thanks for the answer . I  have seen google news always detects my location and makes me landed on local content first  . but as you said that is dependent on my public IP Now i understand that . but still I want to know what Google Public Dns is different from my ISP's dns

Comment: It isn't different from you ISP's DNS, even you can launch a DNS server at your home, your OS needs an IP for a Server (DNS) that runs the software for name resolution, it can be any IP. EDIT: This might clear it more for you https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/

Comment: Google's DNS has a couple of advantages. It is easy to remember, they don't resolve unregistered domain names in order to serve ads like many ISP's, you can flush the cache via their website, and google is pretty good about keeping up with speed and security issues. The major downside would be they have even more detailed information on where you go on the web.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that CDNs can rely on DNS geo-location (geodns) to determine where your content is served from, so while it's technically accurate that there's no effect on your location per se, there are potential geographical effects that will occur based on the DNS servers you choose to use.